# How can I get all order tracking numbers in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I have order object and I need to get all shipped package tracking numbers. I tried following code, but it returns nothing even orders I tried had packages sent with tracking numbers.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
$trackingNumbers = $order->getTrackingNumbers();
```

Order object is not null, because it returns data for other methods like getShippingMethod etc.

If I click from "Shipping & Handling" link "Information Track Order", then popup shows all tracking numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this..

```
 $shipmentCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_collection')
->setOrderFilter($order)
->load();
```

foreach ($shipmentCollection as $shipment){
    $shipment->getAllTracks(); 
}

Edit:-

```
foreach ($shipmentCollection as $shipment){


foreach($shipment->getAllTracks() as $tracknum)
            {
                $tracknums[]=$tracknum->getNumber();
            }
}
```

Now $tracknums will have the array of tracking numbers.

Comment: Change the top part to: `$shipmentCollection = $order->getShipmentsCollection();`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
$orderIncrementId = 100000016; // YOUR ORDER INCREMENT ID;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
$trackNumber = array();
foreach ($order->getTracksCollection() as $track){
    $trackNumber[] = $track->getNumber();
}
```